# RecyclerView always removes the last item from view and errors when removing item at position 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have been battling with RecyclerView for the last 2 days. Unlike any time in the past, I want to have swipe to dismiss functionality.

I followed
[this guide](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf)

The only difference here that I have implemented is instead of using a predefined array for input, I have an API response to populate the data. All that seems to be good, when I open the recyclerview the items populate as they should. In the order that they should.

Here is where the fun begins. If I try to swipe to dismiss the first item I get an IndexOutOfBounds error. Thats cute, searching I found that some choose to set a new List based on the first list, remove the item and then re-assign the original list to the new list. notifyDataSetChanged() when done. No more error BUT no animation of the recycler view to bring the 2nd item to the top of the list. any time notifyDataSetChanged() is called the list does NOT move. I scroll down and back up and the item is back. Or so I thought.

After playing with this for a while I noticed that while the information in the first item appeared to the be the original first item, its got an ID of the second item in the list and the last item in the view is now missing.

Here is an example:

1. text = Fox id = a
2. text = Dog id = b
3. text = Pig id = c

I swipe dismiss 1 from the list, this is what the UI shows

1. text = Fox id = b
2. text = Dog id = c

Lots of code to embed here and its throwing errors trying to do so, gist is here https://gist.github.com/baggednismo/2840d0f777438d29673bc29096153970

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: BTW: You are always creating the same type of view for each row - you should either not override getItemViewType() in your adapter, or always have it return 0. Your current implementation will cause a ton of creation, as views can only be reused if they happen to be used at the same row for which they were created.

Comment: BTW#2: You should very rarely (if ever) set view holders to not be recycleable. This causes even more unnecessary view creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Scott Stanchfield was very much correct on his input. The noted changes in his comments and answer cleaned up the view to help me find the actual view related issue. The suggestions are still implemented and are part of the solution.

onBindViewHolder() created the view of items of which it was creating the line items based on the original API response order and not the list order recyclerview was handling. onBindViewHolder() is called each time a new item is to appear in the list on scroll and this was the problem. This works fine on the very first inflation of the list however once the item was removed and scrolling back to the top the first item appeared to be the item dismissed.

Original:

```
KitchenOrdersResponse.Item mItem = mKitchenOrdersResponse.getItems().get(i);
```

Resolution:

```
KitchenOrdersResponse.Item mItem = mItems.get(i);
```

Comment: The actual underlying issue was that the list was being set to the response model in the onBindViewHolder method instead of the modified list. This caused the strange UI effect that the first item was removed but the last item actually dropped when in reality the recyclerview list was correct but the data displayed in the recyclerview was incorrect. Your responses were not incorrect either. I created a new post to sum up your suggestions and also to include the biggest offender which was the itemView's data assignment.

Comment: As I was correct, can you change my answer to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `setHasStableIds(true)` and the overridden `getItemId()` from your adapter.

You're telling the `RecyclerView` that the n<sup>th</sup> view will always represent the same item in the list, and it's getting upset when you remove one of the items.

(I just tried a very simplified example with `setHasStableIds(true)` and got a similar exception; it worked fine when I removed it and the `getItemId()`)

Note that your call to `notifyItemDeleted()` is preferable to replacing the entire list, but if you did want or need to replace the entire list, you should look at using `DiffUtil` to determine and make the appropriate changes to the list, and it will do all the cool animation if the same items are still present.

If you want to see my example, it's at https://gist.github.com/javadude/dec1862b075338790f023b42e01fd953 (but it's in kotlin)

Comment: Ok, as per your above comments I have commented out getItemID(), getItemViewType(), setHasStableIDs() and setIsRecyclable(false) and while the animations are working as I expect them to, the list is still dropping the last item. Now the first item drops and animated the list up but when i scroll down to the bottom the last item is missing and when i scroll back up the item i dismissed is back.